# CPU stepping and BIOS support

Tags: cpu, bios

My Z77 motherboard supports a number of Xeon CPUs, which I'd like to upgrade to since they're a little bit cheaper than an i7. The CPU support list for my mobo indicates support for E0 stepping for two of these Xeons (1230v2 and 1240v2), and E1 for the rest. I'm eyeing a 1240v2, but it's E1 stepping. Will it still work, is the CPU support list just what was tested and not a complete list? Or is there a high probability I won't be able to boot?

Comment: The list is complete.  You can safely assume any CPU not listed on that list will not work on that motherboard.

Comment: Bios updates sometimes add support for newer processors an steppings.

Comment: @Moab - Indeed;  Normally the list would be updated at that time.  It either will be listed in the change for the BIOS/UEFI firmware update or in that compatibility list specifically.

Comment: @Ramhound this is not always 100% true, I have updated Dell bios's and gotten many new features not listed in the errata, sometimes they remove features also, without warning.

Comment: It's entirely possible that an E1 stepping for that CPU wasn't available when they made that list and they were just unable to test it and it will work fine. There certainly is no guarantee that it will work.

Comment: @Moab Dell is horrible about documentation so no suppose there

Comment: They are not the only ones, try Asus!